# ClickOnce application install with new assembly identity

Tags: installation, clickonce

We have created a ClickOnce application using [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008).

I would like to have two unique installations of the same application, one which is a TEST application and one which is a LIVE application.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to specify (in the project properties) the uniqueness between the applications.

Every time I try to install the LIVE application it informs me that the application is already installed (as I have the test application already installed).

I want to be able to install both.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate installer for the test app. Give it a different name and installation path. If using a Visual Studio setup project then use a different Product Code (see the project's properties window).